# Are there reasons to import subpackage or submodules without naming them instead of just importing the parent?

Tags: python, python-import

In Python 3, is there a difference between

```
import os.path
os.path.join(a,b)
```

and

```
import os
os.path.join(a,b)
```

except that the latter is shorter?
(I know about `import os.path as path` but I'm talking only about the unnamed import form. I found it in some code and was wondering why it was used)

Comment: If you import a submodule, you only import part of the module which helps reduce size of the imported file. Importing is basically pasting the code in your current script

Answer (score 1):

If a package does not include a module in its `__init__.py`, then

```
package.module
```

will not work even if you have already imported `pacakge` unless you also do

```
import package.module
```

This does not apply to `package`=`os` and `module`=`path` (`os` is actually a module (contained in `os.py`) that imports another module, `path` somewhere in its code)